# Is it possible to take an amount from a column and subtract a subquery from that amount?

Tags: sql, subquery

I've been running into an issue trying to fix a query that I did not write. Heres the problem:

I have an amount from a single column and I need to take that amount and subtract the sum of another number. The number I am subtracting may be zero based on if/then logic(if date >= parameter). This is why I believe I need a subquery

This is standard oracle sql. I've tried subtracting the subquery directly in the same line but something is not working. The following code is in the FROM statement

```
FROM 

(SELECT hca.account_number customer_number,
       hp.party_name customer_name ,



TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(substr(   Nvl( Decode( :P_CURRENCY, 'Entered', apsa.amount_due_original, (apsa.amount_due_original* Nvl( apsa.exchange_rate, 1 ))), 0 )  -    


 SELECT (CASE WHEN 
       ara.gl_date < NVL(:P_AS_OF_DATE,SYSDATE) 
        THEN (Nvl( Decode( :P_CURRENCY, 'Entered', 
              NVL(araa.amount_applied,0), NVL(araa.amount_applied,0)* Nvl( 
                 apsa.exchange_rate, 1 )), 0 )
            ELSE 0)),1,15),9999999999999999.99)) balance_due,
```

I'm just getting an error message when I run the code. Would it be possible to put the subquery in the next from clause, give it a name, and subtract like that?

Comment: Please show the entire query. Not clear why ` .. - SELECT (CASE ..)` why not just ` .. - CASE ..` and where is `END` of the `CASE`

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you need or what the problem (what is the error message?) is without a complete SQL or a complete explanation of what your data is and what you expect to see. Please add more detail.